# How to manually set "foundation watch" port?

Tags: css, npm, sass, zurb-foundation

I had a little problem.
Recently I scaffold a project using foundation-cli.
And then I use "foundation watch" command or "npm start" to serve the site
but it doesn't show on which port it runs.

In the docs they said "localhost:8080"

but I tried there and it doesn't showed anything.

I have tried to use netstat -peanut to search the running port but can't found it anywhere.

Is there any way that I could do to specify the port myself ?

and it seems, foundation build doesn't work either, it didn't produce any dist/ folder

I need the live reload, etc.

did the foundation-cli doesn't work anymore ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen `config.yml` in root folder of your project? There is a lot of useful stuff such a **first line** where you can set your **port** as you need.

Default **PORT** is **8000**

```
# Your project's server will run on localhost:xxxx at this port
PORT: 8000
```